# Which log should I use when debugging starting a web server on boot

Tags: systemd

**Ubuntu 18.04**

I'm trying to make Gunicorn web server start on boot.

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon

[Service]
# the specific user that our service will run as
User=pcask
Group=pcask

WorkingDirectory=/home/michael/PycharmProjects/pcask/pcask
ExecStart=gunicorn pcask.wsgi
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Permissions**

```
pcask@tmpgmv:~/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages$ ls -la |grep gunicorn
drwxrwxr-x   7 pcask pcask   4096 Jul 28 19:32 gunicorn
drwxrwxr-x   2 pcask pcask   4096 Jul 28 19:32 gunicorn-20.0.4.dist-info
```

On reboot the server is not running. Namely when I open my websie, it shows 502 Bad gateway. This means that Gunicorn is not running.

Could you tell me whether there is an error log where I can see what went wrong when this service file was used on boot. And whether it was used at all.

**ADDED LATER**

```
$ sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.service
[sudo] password for pcask: 
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-08-14 12:36:57 MSK; 1min 11s ago
  Process: 439 ExecStart=/home/pcask/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn pcask.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 439 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 14 12:36:57 tmpgmv systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Aug 14 12:36:57 tmpgmv systemd[439]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Aug 14 12:36:57 tmpgmv systemd[439]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/pcask/pcask/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn: Permission denied
Aug 14 12:36:57 tmpgmv systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 14 12:36:57 tmpgmv systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

systemd uses its own logging.  The command for viewing it is

```
journalctl
```

You can use

```
journalctl -u gunicorn.service
```

to trace a specific service.

Some other examples:

```
journalctl --since="2020-01-01 10:00:00"
journalctl --since "30 min ago"
journalctl _PID=1000
```

- make sure the service is active. Check `sudo systemctl status  gunicorn.service` and if inactive you can use `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn` to make it active.
- make sure the service starts after all other required services are started. Starting gunicon before nginx or your network is up wont work.  Something worth noting: your unit is lacking a `After=network.target` in the `[UNIT]` section.

Assuming your gunicorn works when manually started you do not need the nginx logs but just in case those are:

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: sudo systemctl status  gunicorn.service shows that it is inactive. Could you give me a hint what to do?

Comment: see the edit :)

Comment: Could yo have a look. I edited my initial post: added permissions and what journalctl is showing now. Something with permissions.